# h:inputText inside c:forEach not saving elements in List

Tags: jsf, foreach, jstl

I'm trying to have two `<c:foreach>` in which one is to show different days and each day has 8 rows with 3 different inputboxes.

Here is the code

```
<h:form>
    <c:forEach begin="0" end="#{treningNovi.dana-1}" varStatus="loop">
        <c:forEach varStatus="j" begin="0" end="7">
            <h:inputText id="set" value="#{treningNovi.set[j.index+(loop.index*8)]}"/>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>

    <h:commandButton value="Spremi" 
                     action="#{treningNovi.SpremiVjezbe}"
                     styleClass="btn btn-primary" />
</h:form>
```

First `foreach` represents days and second `foreach` adds inputText fields.

Here is my bean class

```
@ManagedBean(name="treningNovi")
public class TreningNovi {

    private List<Integer> set;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initList() {
        set = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    public String SpremiVjezbe() {
        System.out.println(set);
        return "index";
    }

    public List<Integer> getSet() {
        return set;
    }
}
```

For some reason it doesnt save elements properly in list and list is empty after pressing button Spremi. Anyone know the solution? Thank you

Note: I tried using j.index and numbers instead j.index+(loop.index*8) but none of them seems to work so index is not the problem

Also list has `List<Integer> set`  but code didnt get formatted correctly and I dont know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Initialize list with values in `@PostConstruct` and it should work. Now it is trying to insert values to non-existing elements (like set[5], but the list size is 0 so it can't be done).